# What's the means of this piece of go codes which generated by thrift

Tags: go

This is piece of codes which generated by thrift official tutorial:
https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/go

I'm new to go, and could not guess what's the purpose of the codes from the comment.

Googled with some keywords but no lucks.

```
package tutorial

import(
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "reflect"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/apache/thrift/lib/go/thrift"
    "shared"

)

// (needed to ensure safety because of naive import list construction.)
var _ = thrift.ZERO
var _ = fmt.Printf
var _ = context.Background
var _ = reflect.DeepEqual
var _ = bytes.Equal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking at is generated by a computer program.

This particular computer program is defective / stupid: it imports packages that do not require importing in some cases, just in case it generated *different* code in which importing those packages would have been required.  In other words, *before* looking at what code it will generate, it just imports a bunch of things.

To make up for this deficiency, after importing things it *might* not use otherwise, it has some `var` declarations that make the Go compilers think that those things *are* used, so that the compiler does not complain that (e.g.) `fmt` or `bytes` did not need to be imported.

A smarter code-generator would inspect the code it is about to generate, figure out which imports are actually required, and emit those imports and skip the dummy `var` lines.

(That is what the comment phrase:

```
naive import list construction
```

means: the code-generator naively generated a particular set of imports, without looking at the rest of the code it was generating.)